# Date and datetime set to null in beforeValidate transforms to '0000-00-00' and throws error

Tags: validation, date, datetime, sails.js, waterline

I've looked quite extensively around for an answer to how to handle my date-related problem, but I can't seem to find a proper answer anywhere.

I'm using SailsJS (beta) with Waterline as the data-handler. My case is as follows:

My User-model is as such:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    (.. some attributes ..),
    birthDate: {
      type: 'date',
      required: false
    }

  },

  // Modifies user input before validation
  beforeValidation: function(user, cb){
    // Make sure birthdate is not saved as 0000-00-00
    if(!user.birthDate || user.birthDate == '0000-00-00'){
      user.birthDate == null;
    }
    cb(null, user);
  },
}
```

The beforeValidation()-function triggers as it should, but I always gets thrown an error as follows. This seems to be the case for both `date` and `datetime` types in Waterline models.

```
warn: Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid
at WLValidationError.WLError (C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\error\WLError.js:33:18)
at new WLValidationError (C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\error\WLValidationError.js:20:28)
at C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\validate.js:44:43
at allValidationsChecked (C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:181:5)
at done (C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:128:19)
at C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:25:16
at C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:162:23
at Object.async.each (C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:114:20)
at validate (C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\validations.js:142:11)
at C:\web\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:118:13

Invalid attributes sent to User:
  birthDate
    `undefined` should be a date (instead of "0000-00-00", which is a string)
```

How do I set the birthDate to null in the database using sailsjs/waterline?
I hope someone can help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
cb(null, user);
```

to

```
cb();
```

And you have a type-mistake in the if-statement:

```
user.birthDate == null;
```

have to be

```
user.birthDate = null;
```